# The one is wrong is/are you

Tags: sentence-construction

Help me to fix this sentence because it doesn't sound good to me:

> The one is wrong is you!

I believe there is redundancy in that sentence, but I can't explain. Probably the "is"? A part of me thinks that I should use "are", but then I remember a phrase like:

> It's you!

However, even if that's correct, it still sounds mouthful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jeffrey has showed in a comment, the correct sentence would be:

> The one ***who*** is wrong is you!

You can also use *that* instead of *who* if you must, but *who* is preferable.

You could also express the same meaning by using an [it-cleft sentence](https://www.thoughtco.com/it-cleft-sentence-term-1691086):

> It is you that/who is wrong!